How do i convert a binary file with extension .GRD to NeCDF in R?
I have a binary file of temperature with an extension.GRD. I downloaded it from IMD gridded temperature data at a resolution of 1 degree by 1 degree. [IMD High resolution 1.0 By 1.0 degree gridded daily temperature data (1951-2018)*. This data is arranged in 31x31 grid points. Lat 7.5N, 8.5N ... 36.5, 37.5 (31 Values). Long 67.5E, 68.5E ... 96.5, 97.5 (31 Values). For leap years, data for 366 days are included.]
example of file name: Maxtemp_MaxT_1955.GRD
I want to convert it (binary file) to NetCDF first and then to raster brick. As it is daily data, it has 365 rasters; I will convert it to brick and then sum it annually, and then take the mean of that in my feature polygons by doing zonal statistics. Before extracting the data, I want to change the resolution of the raster from 1 degree by 1 degree to 0.5 degree by 0 degree.

How do I read binary files with extension .GRD in r and convert them to NetCDF in r (Additional: .GRD file is a single file. It doesn't have any supplement information file.
How do I resample rasters to get them in resolution 0.5 degree to 0.5 degree in r?

I tried reading and converting binary files to NetCDF in r. But i didn't get progress.

If the file has a standard spatial data format, this could work
library(terra)
f <- "Maxtemp_MaxT_1955.GRD"
x <- rast(f)
y <- writeCDF(x, gsub("GRD$", "nc", f))

Otherwise, some more work is needed, but I would need an example file to be able to say more.
